# Proof verification: $M \cap N \subseteq M$ and $M \subseteq M \cup N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Theorem.** Let $M, N, L$ be sets. Then the following assertions hold:

(1) $M \cap N \subseteq M$

(2) $M \subseteq M \cup N$

*Proof is left as an exercise.*

---

My attempt:

$\\$

**(1)** We have to show that the following assertion
"$\forall x : x \in (M \cap N) \implies x \in M$" is true.

By definition, $M \cap N := \{x \mid x \in M \land x \in N\}$. If "$x \in M$" and "$x \in N$" are true, then $M \cap N$ is true. Resulting in an implication with two true assertions, and hence is true.

We could write that as $\exists x : x \in (M \cap N) \implies x \in M$. (Not quite really sure if this line is correct)

$\\$

**(2)** We have to show that the following assertion "$\forall x : x \in M \implies x \in (M \cup N)$" is true.

By definition, $M \cup N := \{x \mid x \in M \lor x \in N\}$. If either "$x \in M$", "$x \in N$" or both, are true, then $M \cup N$ is true. Resulting in an implication with two true assertions, and hence is true.

We could write that as $\exists x : x \in M \implies x \in (M \cup N)$ (Again, not quite really sure if this line is correct)

---

Liesen, J., Mehrmann, V. 2015. Linear Algebra. Berlin, Germany.: Springer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace $\exists$ with $\forall$. A way to make the proof more compact is:
$$x\in M \cap N \implies x\in M \land x\in N \implies x\in M \implies M\cap N \subseteq M$$

Comment: Somehow I might find this easier as something like $$\left(\forall x: x\in M \cap N \implies x\in M \land x\in N \implies x\in M\right) \implies M\cap N \subseteq M$$

Comment: @Henry That’s exactly what I wrote :p

Comment: Thanks so much @Tavish and Henry for your help! So, if I am not mistaken could the proof of (2) be the following?

$\\$
$\forall x : x \in M \cup N \implies x \in M \lor x \in N \implies x \in M \implies M \subseteq M \cup N$

Comment: @RoSegura No, don’t forget you want to start with the assumption that $x\in M$ and then show that $x\in M\cup N$! Also, the second last line is wrong.

Comment: @Tavish I upvoted you, but felt you were almost leaving no space to breath

Comment: @Tavish, alright then. So, if $x \in M$ is my assumption, and I am getting this correct the proof would be something like: $M \subseteq M \cup N \implies x \in M \implies x \in M \lor x \in N \implies \exists x : x \in M \cup N$

Comment: @Henry do you mean the formatting?

Comment: @RoSegura The order seems a bit strange. This would be better: $$x\in M \implies x\in M \lor x\in N \implies x\in M\cup N \implies M\subseteq M\cup N$$

Comment: @Tavish, thanks again for the help. Means a lot.

Comment: @Ro Segura Glad I could help.